# How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?

Tags: support, faq, answers, asking-questions, stack-snippets

In the Stack Snippets editor, I can see a drop-down box for including a version of React, but how do I actually create a snippet using React with JSX in it?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/)

Comment: Related non-React version: [*I've been told to do a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)

Comment: Related feature request: [*Add detailed help for Stack Snippets to the editor's “Code” section and the advanced help*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302960/add-detailed-help-for-stack-snippets-to-the-editors-code-section-and-the-adva)

Comment: Related feature request: [One-click framework snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405754/one-click-framework-snippets)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step guide, first summary, then details with pictures. There are a couple of live demonstration snippets after the detailed instructions.

### Summary:

1. Open the Stack Snippets editor by clicking the [image: [<>]] toolbar button.
2. Pick your desired React version from the drop-down on the left-hand side. *(See the details below if you don't see the version you need in the list — note that as of March 2021 **none** of the built-in version options supports hooks, the details below [and a hooks example] say what to do.)*
3. Tick the **Use BabelJS / ES2015** checkbox; it doesn't say explicitly, but this is what enables JSX support, as the Babel configuration used includes JSX handling. (Note: Sadly, [SE hasn't updated the version of Babel standalone that it uses in years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit), so that feature doesn't support shorthand fragments or `async`/`await`. You can enable them if you need them (see the preceding link), it's just awkward.
4. If you're **not** going to use the in-snippet console, this is a good time to un-tick that box.
5. If you have additional libraries, use the **Add an external library** button (or just `script` and `link` tags) to add them.
6. Add your code in the JavaScript panel.

   - If your code is written in TypeScript, comment out the type annotations (and `type` and `interface` declarations) so it's valid JavaScript code.
   - If your code needs **ajax**, you can easily simulate it by using static data and `setTimeout`.
7. If you use Hooks, you can either use them directly on `React` (`React.useState` etc.) or to be more similar to how you probably use them in your real code, destructuring at the beginning (where you probably use `import` in your real code):

   ```js
   const {useState} = React;
   ```

   There's a Hooks example at the end of this answer.
8. At the end of your code, write a call to `ReactDOM.render` (up to v17.x) or `ReactDOM.createRoot` (v18.x+) telling it what to render and where: If you're using the in-snippet console, be sure to define the HTML for an element in the HTML pane and target that element with the `ReactDOM.render` call; if you aren't, you can render directly to `body` if you like. (Rendering to `body` doesn't work if you use the in-snippet console because it overwrites the console's element.)
9. You're ready to run your React/JSX code! Click the **Run** button. Note that there may be a brief delay while scripts are loaded and the JSX is transpiled before your results appear in the results pane. As with any snippet, double-check that your snippet runs the way you mean it to (double-check the web console if not using the in-snippet console) and demonstrates what you want it to demonstrate (your specific issue, if asking a question; or the solution, if posting an answer).

#### Notes:

- The version of Babel used by Stack Snippets doesn't support `<>` and `</>` for fragments, so use `<React.Fragment>` and `</React.Fragment>` instead.
- The versions of React offered by the drop-down get out of date quickly, but you can easily edit to use an up-to-date version. For instance, if you select "React v16.6.3` from the drop-down, you can edit the script tags it includes to use v18.2.0 if you like.

### Details:

1. Open the Stack Snippets editor by clicking the [image: [<>]] toolbar button:

   [image: An image of the toolbar with the Stack Snippets button circled (it is the seventh button from the left, with the title "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M"]
2. Pick your desired React version from the drop-down:

   [image: An image of the Stack Snippet interface with the ReactJS dropdown expanded and circled]

   **Note A:** At the moment, the list goes up through v16.6.3. To use hooks and such, you'll need later versions. You can grab the latest from a CDN (like https://cdnjs.com/); use the "UMD" versions. For instance, to use v17.0.2:

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
   ```

   Or to use v18.2.0:

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
   ```

   **Note B:** The version of Babel used by Stack Snippets doesn't support `<>` and `</>` for fragments, so use `<React.Fragment>` and `</React.Fragment>` instead.

   **Note C:** To use hooks, be sure to use v16.8 or later, and use `const {useState} = React;` and similar to get the hook functions; see the final example at the end of this answer.
3. Tick the **Use BabelJS / ES2015** checkbox; it doesn't say explicitly, but this is what enables JSX support, as the Babel configuration used includes JSX handling:

   [image: An image of the Stack Snippet interface with the "Use BabelJS / ES2015" checkbox circled]
4. If you're **not** going to use the in-snippet console, this is a good time to un-tick that box.
5. If you have additional libraries, use the **Add an external library** button (or just `script` and `link` tags) to add them:

   [image: An image of the Stack Snippet interface with the Add an external library button circled]

   (You can find just about everything hosted on a CDN somewhere, such as https://cdnjs.com/ [I have no affiliation with them].)
6. Add your code:

   [image: An image of the Stack Snippet interface with JavaScript code entered into the JavaScript area]

   - If our code needs **ajax**, you can easily simulate it with static data and `setTimeout`:

     Instead of:

     ```js
     fetch("/some/resource")
     .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
          }
          return response.json();
     })
     .then(data => {
          // ...use data here...
     })
     .catch(/*...*/);
     ```

     you'd do:

     ```js
     setTimeout(() => {
          // ...use data here...
     }, 800);
     ```

     or if you need a promise:

     ```js
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800, {/*...data here...*/}));
     ```
7. If you use Hooks, you can either use them directly on `React` (`React.useState` etc.) or to be more similar to how you probably use them in your real code, destructuring at the beginning (where you probably use `import` in your real code):

   ```js
   const {useState} = React;
   ```

   There's a Hooks example at the end of this answer.
8. At the end of your code, write a call to `ReactDOM.render` telling it what to render and where.

   As usual, you'll want to define an element in the HTML box:

   ```html
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```

   ...and then code the `ReactDOM` call like this, to render into that element:

   ```js
   // v15.x, v16.x, v17.x
   ReactDOM.render(
       <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
       document.getElementById("root")
   );
   ```

   or

   ```js
   // v18.x+
   ReactDOM.createRoot(
       document.getElementById("root")
   ).render(
       <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />
   );
   ```

   Example (there's a live copy below as well):

   [image: An image of the Stack Snippet interface with the code above added]
9. You're ready to run your React/JSX code! Click the **Run** button. **Make sure that the snippet runs and demonstrates the problem you're trying to show.**

   Note that there may be a brief delay while scripts are loaded and the JSX is transpiled before your results appear in the results pane. As with any snippet, double-check that your snippet runs the way you mean it to (double-check the web console if not using the in-snippet console) and demonstrates what you want it to demonstrate (your specific issue, if asking a question; or the solution, if posting an answer).

   [image: An image of the Stack Snippet interface with the in-snippet console showing results]

#### Live copy of rendering into an element and using the snippet console

React v17.0.2 (see Step 2, Note A of **Details** above for how we got v17.0.2 when the latest in the list is v16.6.3):

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => (
    <div>{props.label}</div>
);

// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {title} = this.props;
        console.log("rendered");
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{title}</div>
                <SFC label="I'm the SFC inside the Thingy" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

React v18.2.0:

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => (
    <div>{props.label}</div>
);

// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {title} = this.props;
        console.log("rendered");
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{title}</div>
                <SFC label="I'm the SFC inside the Thingy" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

#### Live example using Hooks

**Note:** See Step 2, Note A in the **Details** above. To use hooks, you have to provide the React scripts explicitly, not via the drop-down, as the drop-down is outdated.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if I'm adding an external react library and I want to use it? let's say react-bootstrap or any other. Is that possible?

Comment: @AlterLagos - In most cases, yes. Use the "Add an external library" button or add the necessary `script` and/or `link` tags in the HTML pane.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain at all my question. I'm adding `react-bootstrap` from a CDN in a `script` tag, then I don't find a way to use it in my snippet code. I tried using `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';` but is throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I don't find a way to assign it to a `const` either, as it seems `import` isn't enabled by default.

Comment: @AlterLagos - You need a build of it that doesn't use `require` or `import`/`export`, such as the "UMD" builds of the React scripts above.

Comment: @Sharcoux - That *is* noted, in the answer above (under **Details**, Step 2). :-) I've edited to add a reminder about that just above the Hooks example at the end.

Comment: As far as I can tell, currently (2020-03-29) react hooks are not available, because the latest reactjs allowed in the dropdown is 16.6.3, and hooks need 16.8.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn - Step 2 explains what to do about that: *"At the moment, the list goes up through v16.6.3. To use hooks and such, you'll need later versions. You can grab the latest from a CDN (like https://cdnjs.com/); use the "UMD" versions. For instance, to use v16.8.4:"* followed by script tag examples for 16.8.4 (out of date now). There's also the "Live example using Hooks".

Comment: @AlterLagos You have to use the CDN variant. Most of the times these are provided in the "getting started" or "installation" section of the library documentation. If you can't find them there you can always try https://cdnjs.com or https://unpkg.com. `react-bootstrap` does offer its own [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#browser-globals). Here the documentation also says that the components are available via the `ReactBootstrap` global. So you can do `const { Button } = ReactBootstrap;` (1/2)

Comment: If the global is not documented I often use use something like `console.log(Object.keys(window).filter(name => name.match(/bootstrap/i)))` to find all globals that have "bootstrap" (case insensitive) in the name. Here you replace `/bootstrap/i` with something that is most likely going to match. If you cannot find it using this method you can always use `console.log(Object.keys(window).sort())` to display all globals in alphabetical order. However this list will be a lot longer. (2/2)

Comment: Note that by checking **Use BabelJS / ES2015** you do enable JSX support, however ES2015 does **not** support `async`/`await`, so you have to work with promises.

Comment: @3limin4t0r cool, for the next time I'll give a try. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @3limin4t0r - The real problem there is that [SE hasn't updated the version of Babel standalone that it uses in years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit).

Comment: Best doc ever! Thank you.  Can you point to something even 10% good for vuejs?  Like "Hello World" where "World" comes from data?

Comment: @danh - I'm afraid I don't, no. I've been meaning to look into Vue.js anyway (just on general principle), and if I do I'll do up one of these for it. We could use an Angular one too.

Comment: 2021: The "Tidy" button completely breaks JSX

Comment: @TJ - Yeah. And the libs list is out of date. And the Babel version is so old that it doesn't understand `async` functions (!). And. And. And. :-| But by all means, let's spend more time finding new ways to advertise Teams to SO contributors.

Comment: Can someone add `alt` text descriptions to the images in this answer when they get a chance?

Comment: @Sean Done. Let us know if there's any that don't make sense (or feel free to edit them yourself ;))

Comment: Now if we can actually get any of the many React posters to actually DO/Use this... There are so many non-functioning  code fragments posted for this currently very active technology area instead of just a "post and hope" chance someone replies.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added a [response below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426742/1762224) for getting Babel 7 support.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Stack Snippets use [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) version [6.10.3](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v6.10.3) (circa June 18, 2016).

The following [ES7+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#7th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2016) features are unsupported:

- Async functions (`async`/`await`)
- Optional chaining (`?.`)
- Nullish-coalescing (`??`) and assignment (`??=`)
- Shorthand for `<React.Fragment>` (`<></>`)

As a follow-up to T.J. Crowder's [awesome response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1762224), I have crafted a template using React 18 and Babel 7.

My inspiration came from the following post:

> [Update the version of Babel Standalone (and others) used by Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386096/1762224)

Here is the snippet. Please note that I placed the JSX code inside the HTML viewport of the snippet editor. This is required so that Babel can process the JSX correctly. I added examples of callbacks, effects, states, and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

```css
.App button:last-child {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react">
/* BEGIN ES2017 (ES8) React code... */
const { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;

const App = ({ initialCount = 0, step = 1, title = 'APP_TITLE' }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('...');
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount ?? 0);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1');
      const person = await response.json();
      setName(person?.name);
    })();
  }, []);

  const updateCount = useCallback((event) => {
    setCount((currentCount) => currentCount + step);
  }, []);

  const resetCount = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(initialCount);
  }, [initialCount]);

  const clickDisabled = useMemo(() => count <= 0, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{name}, you have {count} tries left.</p>
      <>
        <button disabled={clickDisabled} onClick={updateCount}>Click me</button>
        <button onClick={resetCount}>Reset</button>
      </>
    </div>
  );
};
// Render it
ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<App initialCount={10} step={-1} title="Example using Hooks" />);
/* END ES2017 (ES8) React code... */
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/7.23.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great stuff! Now if only SE Inc would bother to spend the brief amount of engineering time it would take to [fix Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets).