# How do I create a Vue.js Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I found [detailed instructions here on how to create a Stack Snippet for React](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support), but I have been unable to figure out how to do so for a Vue.js component.

**How do I create a runnable Stack Snippet of a Vue.js component?**

Comment: It's not super locatable, but a tutorial for converting a Vue component into a Snippet exists at the very end of the [vue.js tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/info).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is a (slightly updated) direct copy from something [I initially wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28129001) into the end of the [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/info); I figure it's a good starting point for creating a more comprehensive resource.

I'm currently unfamiliar with Vue 3, so I'm unsure about whether or how much this guidance needs to be updated to be compatible.

All are encouraged to edit this in any way to improve its usefulness as a resource!

---

#### Converting a Vue Component into a Stack Snippet

It is often useful to share [runnable snippets of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) in questions regarding Vue components. Since Stack Snippets can't natively run Vue single file components (`.vue` files), it's necessary to do a little conversion work.

To create a Stack Snippet containing Vue in a Stack Overflow post, make sure you:

1. Import Vue into the HTML section of the snippet

   - You can do this through the sidebar menu of the snippet editor itself, if it includes your desired version:
     [image: Vue version select in snippet editor sidebar]
   - Or by manually adding a `<script>` tag referencing the version you need:
     (eg. `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>`)
   - NOTE: It's important that the Vue import is *before* other imports of libraries that depend on Vue (eg. Vue Router)
2. Wrap component JavaScript with `new Vue({...})`

   - Replace `default export` with `new Vue`, and don't forget the parenthesis `()` around your brackets `{}`
   - Note that you won't be able to use `import` statements, so you should trim everything out of the snippet that's not strictly necessary to understand your question and the problem at hand
   - You may also need to add example data if your component relied on props or APIs
3. Tell the new Vue instance where to render in your HTML

   - Use the [`el` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el) of the new Vue instance to indicate what HTML container Vue should render in (see example below)

You may also want to replace your `<template>` HTML elements with some alternative (ie. `<div>`) if it causes issues.

Starting with something like this:

`HelloWorld.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <input v-model="message">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello World!'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Will end up with something like this:

`HelloWorld.html`

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>

<!-- Don't forget to include Vue from CDN! -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app', //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app"
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello World!'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

You can drop this straight into the HTML section of a snippet, or split it into the HTML and JavaScript sections accordingly. Bear in mind that splitting it may make the code clearer to readers!

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>

<!-- Don't forget to include Vue from CDN! -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app', //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app"
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello World!'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

### Vue 3 composition API

`<script setup>` doesn't work with CDN scripts since it's compile-time syntactic sugar. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70960489/6243352) for details and a partial workaround using `setup()`. Here's a refined version:

```js
const {ref} = Vue;

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const message = ref("hello");
    return {message};
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

And a larger example:

```js
"use strict";

const {computed, defineComponent, ref} = Vue;

const Test = defineComponent({
  template: "#test",
  props: ["labelName"],

  setup(props) {
    const name = ref("");
    const names = ref([]);

    const onReset = () => {
      name.value = "";
    };
    const submit = () => {
      names.value.push(name.value);
      name.value = "";
    };

    return {name, names, onReset, submit, props};
  }
});

const App = defineComponent({
  template: "#app-template",
  components: {Test},

  setup() {
    const message = ref("hello world");
    const user = ref(null);

    const reversedMessage = computed(() =>
      [...message.value].reverse().join("")
    );

    Vue.onMounted(() => {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          user.value = json;
        });
    });

    return {message, reversedMessage, user};
  }
});

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <p>{{reversedMessage}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
  <pre v-if="this.user">{{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}}</pre>
  <pre v-else>loading...</pre>
  <test label-name="test label"></test>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="test">
  <form @submit.prevent="submit" @reset="onReset">
    <div>
      <label>{{labelName}}
        <input v-model="name" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button type="reset">reset</button>
  </form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="n of names">{{n}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

And as a module:

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>

<script type="module">
import {createApp, ref} from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js";

createApp({
  setup() {
    const message = ref("hello");
    return {message};
  }
}).mount("#app");
</script>
```

[tao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/tao) has a number of excellent Vue 3 stack snippets using the above workaround. Here are a few selections:

- [How does Computed work in Vue 3 script setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71458861/how-does-computed-work-in-vue-3-script-setup/71459106#71459106)
- [how to reset one of data in pinia state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72025169/how-to-reset-one-of-data-in-pinia-state/72025349#72025349)
- [Vue 3 global properties are not reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083553/vue-3-global-properties-are-not-reactive/74083696#74083696)
- [Change Vue.js data from outside Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456423/change-vue-js-data-from-outside-vue-js/71457890#71457890)
- [Vue 3 - How to execute a function on binding instance in custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157194/vue-3-how-to-execute-a-function-on-binding-instance-in-custom-directive/74157483#74157483)

Another good snippet example is [How to use Axios with Vue 3 Composition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440230/how-to-use-axios-with-vue-3-composition-api/71440583#71440583).

#### Vue 3 options API

Here's a Vue 3 snippet for the options API.

```js
const App = {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "hello world",
    };
  },
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Here's a larger example with multiple components and assorted functionality:

```js
"use strict";

const Test = {
  name: "Test",
  template: "#test",
  props: ["labelName"],
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      names: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onReset() {
      this.name = "";
    },
    submit() {
      this.names.push(this.name);
      this.name = "";
    },
  },
};

const App = {
  name: "App",
  template: "#app-template",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "hello world",
      user: null,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Test,
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.user = json;
      });
  },
  computed: {
    reversedMessage() {
      return [...this.message].reverse().join("");
    },
  },
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <p>{{reversedMessage}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
  <pre v-if="this.user">{{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}}</pre>
  <pre v-else>loading...</pre>
  <test label-name="test label"></test>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="test">
  <form @submit.prevent="submit" @reset="onReset">
    <div>
      <label>{{labelName}}
        <input v-model="name" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button type="reset">reset</button>
  </form>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="n of names">{{n}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Using `https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.global.prod.js` disables the production tip, per [How do I turn off the productionTip warning in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513579/how-do-i-turn-off-the-productiontip-warning-in-vue-3), at the expense of suppressing useful debug logs you might want to see during development. Use `https://unpkg.com/vue@3` for verbose output.

Another way to suppress the productionTip warning is to add the CSS `.as-console-wrapper{display:none!important}`, but this also hides errors and all other logs.

To be a bit more precise than the CSS solution at the expense of uglier code, you can add the following JS to prune out only the production tip row from the console:

```js
setTimeout(() => [...document.querySelectorAll(".as-console-row")]
  .forEach(e => e.textContent.includes("build of Vue") && e.remove()
), 0);
```

Comment: is it possible to include a `three.js` snippet [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777842) inside the `Vue` snippet? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: is there an example that you are aware of?

Comment: None that I'm aware of offhand.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with an object-formatted component (with <template> tags, as opposed to a single file component).

Select a recent version of vue from the "Options" on the left pane, then...

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'World'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello {{ message }}</h1>
</div>
```