# Support newer versions of Vue.js 3 in Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Why don't we still have any of the Vue.js 3 versions close to end of 2023, available to choose when due to GitHub, Vue.js 3 has been with us [since the end of 2019](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)
(of course, we still can add it as an external library)?

[image]

Comment: The answer to "how to" - just manually link to a CDN version of Vue 3+. After all, it's basically the same as choosing from the list in the end. The answer to "why?" - because the list of pre-provided versions linking to a CDN copy hasn't been updated. For quite a while.

Comment: I don't think the dupe is entirely appropriate, although, to be fair, OP has asked two separate questions. The composition API has special syntax that I don't think is supported by stack snippets. Can the composition API even be run in the browser without a build step? That would seem to be a prerequisite to stack snippets supporting it. Somewhat related: [How do I create a Vue.js Stack Snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417263/how-do-i-create-a-vue-js-stack-snippet/417270#)

Comment: Questions should be a single question or, perhaps, more than one *very* closely related question. Your "how to" question is very different from your "why" question, even though both are about vue.js, particularly when looked at from the point of view of future readers. That they are significantly different should have been hinted at by needing to use different required tags for each of the two. Please [edit] this question to be one or the other of those two questions. You're welcome to create a new, additional, question for the one of those two which you edit out of this question.